# Body image position between iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, html, ipad

I'm making a website and I've got it working on the Mac and the iPad. When I see it on the iPhone, one of the pages doesn't place the background-image correctly.
I'm using 2 background images on the  of the website and I've already set it's height to around 1200px. When I see the same page on the iPhone, all the text wraps up and makes the page longe. My footer image stays in the same position and the text overlaps it. Shouldn't it work as the iPad since I've got all the text wrapped inside a ?
I'm noticing that the problem is that the image is set on the body and as it's not a , it will not follow the increased length of the text.
How can I specify a height of that  background-image specifically for the Mac + iPad and another one for the iPhone?

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#333;
    background:#000;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-image:url(images/gradcinza_top.png), url(images/gradcinza_bot.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x, repeat-x;


    background-position:0px 115px, 0px 950px;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    }
```

On the iPad and the Mac, those 950px put the footer image on the exact place I want it. In the iPhone, since I have less area to present the text it simply makes it longer. I need something to say to the website to put the  background-image on on position while it's being viewed on the Mac and iPad and another condition to specify a new position for the iPhone.

Thank you.

Comment: You never ever should set up scripts or styles for a specific device. Try to use the CSS media query to get different versions based on the screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read some Responsive Web Design Guidelines..Use CSS Media Queries for this...

e.g.:- 
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/